# How to use Icelink stream audio to kurento and test Kurento get audio stream?

Tags: c#, webrtc, kurento

I use Icelink Conference for streaming audio to kurento. How to test kurento gets audio stream?  I develop c#Icelink webrtc for stream audio to Kurento server like this.

```
     Sender = new FM.IceLink.Conference([Kurento IP], 8888, new Stream[]
        {
             audioStream_sender,
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how IceLink works, but I'm sure that what you are doing doesn't do what you think it does. Basically, you'll need to have a WebRTC endpoint from IceLink, negotiate a connection with a WebRTC endpoint from Kurento. WebRTC negotiation implies exchanging SDPs and ICE candidates, which you will have to send between the two servers.

I'm afraid that since there is no C# library for signalling Kurento, you'll either have to use the [protocol](https://doc-kurento.readthedocs.io/en/stable/mastering/kurento_protocol.html) raw, or create a small server app based in the Java or JS clients.